# MySQL can't use a user that I create

Tags: mysql, database

In MySQL I create two users:

```
CREATE USER 'Bob'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'p'
CREATE USER 'Alice'@'%' IDENTIFIED by 'a'
```

And then, when I try to connect with: "mysql -u Alice -p" it fails, telling me

```
Error 1045 (28000) Access denied for user 'Alice'@'localhost'
```

T
The same with Bob.

Anyone knows why occur this?

EDIT:

MySQL asks for the password, and the I putand give me that error.

EDIT 2: I am connecting in remote, not in local, so the only that must work is Alice.

Comment: what about `mysql -u 'Alice'@'%' -pa` ? I've been facing similar problems recently and apparently depending on your version of mysql, you'll have to specify the @... part

Comment: Nop, "Access denied for user 'Alice@%'@'localhost'

Answer (score 0):

Log in as root and do this:

```
GRANT ALL privileges ON *.* TO Bob@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'p' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I do that with Bob and Alice an nothing. I am working in remote, so only Alice must work.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried flushing privileges with that command ?

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a comment in [Using % for host when creating a MySQL user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823854/using-for-host-when-creating-a-mysql-user),

> Actually there is, 'localhost' is special in mysql, it means a
>   connection over a unix socket (or named pipes on windows I believe) as
>   opposed to a TCP/IP socket. using % as the host does not include
>   'localhost' – nos May 30 '12 at 20:45

As a result, if your `mysql -u alice...` command connects using a Unix socket rather than at 127.0.0.1, you'll need to

```
CREATE USER 'Alice'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'a'
```