# Creating a new MySQL user

Tags: mysql

I'm learning how to create a user with a query. I found the following to be working on my localhost, but I'm not sure what the percent sign (%) means. It creates the user `test_user` with `%` as the host "Host", as displayed in phpMyAdmin, instead of a `localhost` Host like for other users I have.

```
CREATE USER 'test_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Also, what would I be doing wrong in assigning privileges to this user?

This doens't work:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON test_db.* TO 'test_user'@'localhost';
```

This works:

```
GRANT SELECT, UPDATE ON *.* TO 'test_user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using % for host when creating a MySQL user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823854/using-for-host-when-creating-a-mysql-user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` character in MySQL is a wildcard character for strings. Having a `%` as the hostname for your user allows them to connect from any host.

You can find more info about it here: [MySQL account name reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-names.html)

Answer (score 1):

`%` is MySQL wildcard, similar to `*` in regexes and several other places.

Here, it decides that the `test_user` can connect from any IP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know % sign is a wildcard in SQL. So it means that the host for test_user is able to connect from any host/ip.