# MySQL 'user'@'%' is not including 'user'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, linux

I've seen other questions like this but this is a little different.

I've created a mysql user with '%' and granted all permissions.

On Mac and Windows: I'm able to login using this.

```
mysql -u user -p<password>
```

On Linux it fails with invalid password for 'user'@'localhost'.

Any idea why? I was hoping that 'user'@'%' is all hosts including localhost as it is behaving in Mac and Windows but it is different on Linux.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using % for host when creating a MySQL user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823854/using-for-host-when-creating-a-mysql-user)

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question myself a while back.
[Using % for host when creating a MySQL user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823854/using-for-host-when-creating-a-mysql-user)

localhost is special to mysql, it's a connection over named pipes or a unix socket. So using % as the host does not include localhost.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you do not connect via sockets ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connecting.html ), try using `127.0.0.1` or set `--protocol=TCP`