# MySQL (MariaDB) authentication failed for 'user'@'localhost' even after user was added

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I created a test user for my database. It is MySQL/MariaDB (running the MySQL server that comes with XAMPP).

Steps to create the test user:

```
CREATE USER 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Next, I tried to log in with a C# WinForms application as that user.

Since I am on my local machine, I just used `127.0.0.1` as the host.

Connection string was: `Server=127.0.0.1; Port=3306; Database=mydb; Uid=user1; Pwd=user1;`

I got the following error message upon trying to open the connection:

`Authentication to host '127.0.0.1' for user 'user1' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'user1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Upon doing a `SELECT host, user, password FROM mysql.user` I get the following:

```
+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
| host      | user  | password                                  |
+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root  |                                           |
| 127.0.0.1 | root  |                                           |
| ::1       | root  |                                           |
| localhost |       |                                           |
| localhost | pma   |                                           |
| %         | user1 | *B9CFB5C1F2F7B45EF0F9A826B2250F6250D85E73 |
+-----------+-------+-------------------------------------------+
```

So, why am I seeing this error message? Since the domain for `user1` is defined as any (`%`), I should be able to connect with this user from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, no?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445917/connect-failed-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes

Comment: Also answer "% doesnt include localhost" : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823854/using-for-host-when-creating-a-mysql-user

Comment: Wow, go figure it was the "localhost" part. Interesting. Of course changing it to my computer's IP address as seen from the Internet worked.

Comment: so then `CREATE USER 'user1'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user1';` presumably fixes one aspect?

Comment: @Drew yes, that fixed it

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the `%` does not include `localhost` due to the differences in how the connection is setup from `localhost` compared to any other IP address. Changing the host name to my computer's public IP address worked, though I will probably add another user entry for the same username but for `localhost` as the domain.