# How to login with 'myuser'@'%' into MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have `'myuser'@'%'` user in MySQL and he is able to modify database. Unfortunately, when I try to login with

```
mysql -umyuser -p
```

it assumes the user is `'myuser'@'localhost'` and does not allow me to operate.

How to fix?

Comment: --host="somehost" --database="sss"?

Comment: what about this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16517566/5303401