# MariaDB: SELECT command denied

Tags: python, mariadb

I am using mysql.connector from Python to access data from a MariaDB but for each select statement I get:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user 'testUser'@'localhost' for table [TABLENAME]
```

... but the rights should be there?

```
MariaDB [DB_NAME]> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'testUser';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for testUser@%                                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'testUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '[PW AS HASH]' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

It used to work but then I played a round with permissions in order to write out a text file from the result of an sql query (directly in MariaDB) - no idea what I did wrong ... how can I fix this back to working?

Comment: If you provide`SELECT User, Host,FROM mysql.use output (as text) and the option file, we may reveal what the issue has been (see my comment son your answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Strangely enough

```
grant all privileges on * to 'testUser'@'localhost' identified by '[PW]';
```

fixed it while

```
grant all on *.* to 'testUser'@'%' identified by '[PW]';
```

did not ...

Comment: Not strange just 2 different user`'testUser'@'%'`is used if no specific user/machine combination is found. But you created`'testUser'@'localhost'`and connect from`localhost , so that user is used. If you connect from`1.2.3.4`the user `'testUser'@'%'is used, unless you have a user named``'testUser'@'%1.2.3.4`

Comment: Ok maybe I was wrong and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823854/using-for-host-when-creating-a-mysql-user) is the answer. Was some days ago since I knew that