# Mysql not listing all Databases for root user

Tags: mysql, database, kubernetes, devops

I have a mysql database running on k8s cluster inside pod. it was previously listing all the databases when i login through `mysql -u root -p` and then entering password. But my application was not able to connect to that database and was showing `1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'ipaddress' (using password: YES)"` there was just one host which is % and user was root

i have updated secrets as well and restart deployment but still it was showing the above error.

then i ran this command to grant all privileges to root user

```
GRANT ALL ON root.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

it creates one more host for root which is localhost. Now when i try to login with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

it is not listing my databases and just showing

[image]

And now host is localhost. what should i do to get my database back.

Comment: Are you running as a statefulset with persistent storage or as a deployment with ephemeral storage?

Comment: Yes statefulset with persistent storage @jordanm

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL permissions are granted for "accounts" which consist of a user name and a host name [[1].](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/account-names.html) So in terms of GRANTS:

```
myuser@127.0.0.1
myuser@192.168.1.1
```

The above are two different users. The wildcard in terms of permissions is `%`. However `%` and `localhost` are mutually exclusive as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823854/using-for-host-when-creating-a-mysql-user).

So having that in mind you would need to run something close to:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'changeme';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_database_name.* TO 'root'@'%';
```

In order to enable connections coming from a different host. Please keep in mind that using the username root should be avoided. Instead, use a dedicated user for your needs.